# Creating folder pattern in Amazon s3 using informatica BDM

Tags: amazon-s3, informatica

We are implementing data lake. To load the landing layer s3 bucket, we use sqoop jobs which does the task of loading data into S3 landing layer bucket.From Amazon s3 landing layer bucket, we are using Informatica Developer tool to pull the files/objects and load it into sanitised layer s3 bucket path - s3://amazon.s3.bucket/YYYYMM/File1.txt( We are maintaining a path for each month load). So, for each month load we are going to create folder like structure in s3 bucket sanitised layer. Through Informatica developer tool, I would like to pass the s3 bucket path of the file  and the file name dynamically using parameter file for both read & write into s3 and by doing this way the file path will be created automatically in Amazon s3 if the path doesn't exists in Amazon s3. I would like to know how do we could pass the details dynamically.

Any idea regarding this implementation in Informatica Developer tool would be really appreciated.

Thanks,
Vijay

Comment: I'm able to resolve the issue now. By using Informatica BDM itself, I'm able to create a folder like structure in aws S3 and create files dynamically. So, the approach I have followed is, using the parameter file I will be passing the S3 bucket name with folder structure and file name. When, I run the mapping with the parameter file automatically parameter value to the S3 Physical data object is getting substituted and creating the files(S3://amazon.s3.data/2018115/New_file.csv).  I could explain in-details, if anyone require the steps to do it.

Comment: Hi I am a newbie, we have a similar requirement, can you please explain a bit more on how are you are able to achieve it, Thanks in advance..